# THREE.JS Texture Mapping on ExtrudeGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a problem with **three.js** and **ExtrudeGeometry**.
I do have a wave-like structure which is made from several individual frames. Each of them is extruded using **ExtrudeGeometry**.

[image: Image of the problem]

I'd like to apply a texture to each frame of the structure which is "wrapped around" the structure. For some reason (possibly wrong UV-mapping?) the texture does not display correctly on the extruded edges where the wave-like surface is out of level. (There are some tiny sections in the picture where the texture wraps correctly). I'm using the following script to apply the textures:

```
// create some simple Geometry
var shape = new THREE.Shape();

shape.moveTo( 0,0 );
shape.lineTo( 0,10 );
shape.lineTo( 100,7 );
shape.lineTo( 100,0 );

var extrudeSettings = {
    steps: 2,
    amount: 10,
    bevelEnabled: false,
    bevelThickness: 0,
    bevelSize: 0,
    bevelSegments: 0
};

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
var texture = new THREE.Texture( image );

texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 0.1, 0.1 );

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture} );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;

scene.add( mesh );
```

Every help is much appreciated! Cheers!

**Edit:**

I've created this image to better illustrate the problem. White Arrows show, how the texture is supposed to wrap around the object. At some very rare spots it actually does!

[image: Texture Wrapping]

Comment: For one thing, you need to set `THREE.RepeatWrapping`, instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But does not solve the problem ...

Comment: Instead of using `ExtrudeGeometry`, consider starting with a basic box and modifying the vertices. Here is a start: https://jsfiddle.net/3trnvd2z/. Make sure you understand each line of code. If you are only going to use `BasicMaterial`, then you don't need scene lights, and you can ignore correcting the normals.

Comment: Thanks a lot, WestLangley! This is awesome. I figured that the texture wraps in a wrong way since UV coordinates are above 1. When i scale down coordinates by 1000 and scale the model up by factor 1000, everything works smoothly...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=geome#webgl_geometry_shapes

at row 70 there is a comment that states that texture.repeat must be set to (0.008, 0.008)